# jQuery Slideshow - Image transition issue

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm making this slideshow but when the images animate I get a white flash THEN the next image. It's a bit difficult to explain so I created this http://jsfiddle.net/2SJ8B/
I imagine it has something to do with my css?

```
#slideshow {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
}​
```

You'll notice it's not a smooth animation but there's something going on. Thanks!

Comment: Please add information about your browser and OS.

Comment: @ArashMilani I don't think the browser or OS is the issue but its window 7 with chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/2SJ8B/5/

The key is the function in the `fadeIn()` command that runs after the fade is complete...

```
$('#slideshow img:first').appendTo('#slideshow').fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $(this).siblings().hide();
});
```

It means that it takes the first image, puts it after the last one (in front of it), and then fades it in.  Once that's done it hides all the other images.  After a second, it repeats.  Now that the dual fading is gone, the white "flash" is gone.

Comment: I think its almost there. Only thing is, the second slideshow doesn't show up right at the beginning. It displays the title just not the image.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did you follow my previous reply?

Comment: Do you think you can take a look at my first comment? Thanks!

Comment: I want to accept this answer but can you take a quick look at my issue?

Comment: It was showing the title from the first one in the list, despite showing the image that was last in the list (`appendTo` puts it at the end.)  Try this... http://jsfiddle.net/2SJ8B/8/

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks. One more problem, I have a 'Next' button that allows  you to manually scroll through the pictures and if you hit 'Next' quickly you end up with a blank image. Not sure why but I think it's because of this line `$(this).siblings().hide();`

Comment: Can you create a new question and post the whole code?  This is getting a bit convoluted now.

Comment: Hey, I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758838/jquery-slideshow-image-transition). I need it to work with a previous and next button. Mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that half-way through the fade, both photos have transparency of 50% and so you see 25% of the white background. This could be perceived as a "flash".
Consider not fading out the outgoing image, instead hiding it after the fade-in completed (using `setTimeout()`).