# jQuery Slideshow Image Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow

I'm having an issue with my jQuery slideshow and I can't seem to figure it out. During the transition of images the slideshow will flash white instead of nicely fading into the next picture. I believe it has something to do with the following lines of code:

```
$('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
```

Clicking the previous and next buttons cause the same issue.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/nyXUt/) a jsFiddle of the slideshow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to show the next image before you start fading out the current one, also you have to do this at the same time, just replace the `fadeIn(1000)` of the .next() image to `show()`, like this http://jsfiddle.net/nyXUt/6/

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work for the slideshow itself but what about the next and previous buttons? I tried to apply your logic but if you click on the next and previous button quickly sometimes it just shows a blank white screen.

Comment: what I would do is, i would add a `transition` variable which will be set true when the animation starts and false when the animation stops, this way multiple clicking won't make the same action start at the same time, here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/nyXUt/13/ also it prevents starting the switchSlide() function at the same time with a click making it confusing

Answer (score 4):

I have re-factored your code and posted it here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/salman/nyXUt/44/**

The main changes are as follows:

**White flash workaround**: you were using fade-out and fade-in. When the two animations are started together, both images become 50% transparent at one point and slide appears whitish (or background colorish). I have used another approach. Using z-index, I place the "to hide" image in front of "to show" image then fade out the "to hide" image:

```css
#slideshow .current {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
#slideshow .animate {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```js
nextItem.addClass("current");
prevItem.removeClass("current").addClass("animate").fadeOut(animDuration, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("animate").css("display", "");
});
```

**setInterval vs setTimeout**: I used setTimeout instead of setInterval which gives more control over timing. The automatic transition is re-scheduled when the user interrupts them with prev/next buttons.

**Animation timings**: I added callbacks and [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to animation to prevent overlapping animations.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the time and effort. I didn't accept the answer because I was trying to write the slideshow myself. I should have mentioned that in the question! +1 for the ideas and help!

Answer (score 2):

maybe minimizing `fadeOut()`, and `fadeIn()` time or `fadeOut(slow)`

Comment: fadeOut and fadeIn are basically a sugarcoated version of animating the opacity. In your jsFiddle, it "flashes white" because the opacity of the pictures is being dropped down in the fadeOut, and when something is less than 100% opaque, obviously the background shines through. In this case, on jsFiddle your background is white. Most of these slideshows will have a dark grey or black background in the div behind them...which is why you're not used to seeing your "white flashes"

Answer (score 2):

When you click next or previous you should stop the interval and previous animations i.e.:

```
clearInterval(run);
$('#slideshow img').stop();
```

When the fade in for the next image is completed you restart the interval i.e.:

```
$('#slideshow img:last').fadeIn(1000, function() { run=setInterval("switchSlide()", speed);})
```

*edit:*
If you click 10 times on a switch button within a second. About 20 animations will run simultaneously.

*edit:*
If you click on next or previous while the image is switching (automatically or otherwise) and the fading is already in progress, the fade will proceed from almost faded to completely faded in a time span of an entire effect (so 1 second). In this time the image will be mostly white.

It might be better to set the fade-out on manual switching faster (like 300ms or even less). This will also improve the users experience.

*edit:*
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCCgc/8/)

Here is the code:

```
var speed = 4000;
run = setTimeout("switchSlide()", speed);
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#caption').html($('#slideshow img:last').attr('title'));

    $('#previous').click(switchBack);
    $('#next').click(switchSlide);

});

function switchSlide() {
    clearInterval(run);
    $('#slideshow img').stop(true,true);
    var jq=$('#slideshow img');
    jq.first().css({'opacity':0}).appendTo('#slideshow').animate({'opacity':1}, 1000, function() { 
        run = setTimeout("switchSlide()", speed); } );
    $('#caption').html(jq.last().attr('title'));
}

function switchBack() {
    clearInterval(run);
    $('#slideshow img').stop(true,true);
    var jq=$('#slideshow img');
    jq.last().animate({'opacity':0},1000, function() { 
        $(this).prependTo('#slideshow').css({'opacity':1}); run = setTimeout("switchSlide()", speed);});
    $('#caption').html(jq.get(1).title);
}
```

Comment: I've already added in code that stops the slideshow when you click next/previous. I just didn't include it in the question because it wasn't the issue. On another note, the white flash between transitions still happens.

Comment: I'm behind my own screen now and I see the obvious white flash now. I updated the code and the fiddle to prevent white flashes

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are fading out at the same time as fading in. Using the standard easing functions, there is a point in the middle where both images are barely visible and a white space is left where the images were.

To fix this, I have switched around the order of you images so that the visible image is on top of the stack. Now we can place the new image on top of the currently visible image and fade it in. Once the new image is fully visible we hide the previous image. This makes for a much smoother transition.

```
$('#slideshow img:first').appendTo('#slideshow');
$('#slideshow img:last').fadeIn(1000, 'swing', function() {
    $('#slideshow img:last').prev().hide();
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyXUt/52/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the delay function which works (only) with jQuery animations.

```
$('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
```

But the best way if you use the provided callbacks as stated by other commenters here.