# jQuery slowly fade in and out, pause, and then repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 images in a list that I would like to slowly fade out, then in, then move on to the next, and repeat until it comes back to the time. So I basically need to use this code, but have it pause until the other 3 are complete, then do it again.

How can I go about doing that?

```
$('#image1').animate({ opacity: 1/3 }, 500);
$('#image1').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
$('#image2').animate({ opacity: 1/3 }, 2000);
$('#image2').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2500);
$('#image3').animate({ opacity: 1/3 }, 3500);
$('#image3').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 4000);
$('#image4').animate({ opacity: 1/3 }, 5000);
$('#image4').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 5500);
```

How do I loop it? Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Try utilizing `.queue()` . can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: For fading use https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: you want to animate images one after another or what? yes, as @erkaner said we need you HTML to solve it faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/8uysuv3q/

```
$(".fade").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(800*index).fadeTo(200, 0.5).fadeTo(200, 1).fadeTo(200, 0.5).fadeTo(200, 1);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't loop - if it did then this would be perfect

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```js
var speed = 2000;
run = setInterval("switchSlide()", speed);
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#caption').html($('#slideshow img:first').attr('title'));

  $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
});

function switchSlide() {
  $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().show().end().appendTo('#slideshow');
  $('#caption').html($('#slideshow img:first').attr('title'));
}
```

```css
#slideshow {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/nature/256/Pink-Flower-icon.png" title="test1" />
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/nature/256/Blue-Flower-icon.png" title="test2" />
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/nature/256/Red-Flower-icon.png" title="test3" />
</div>
```

ADAPTED FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875852/1845408

Comment: Hey erkaner, do you know you can use StackSnippets in your answer?

Comment: It should be the 7th button (next to image) and come up if you press the shortcut ctrl+m. It's called "code snippet" if you hover over the toolbar button.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fadeInOutList($elements, duration, delay) {
     if(!$elements.size()) return
     
     $elements.first().fadeIn(duration, function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
          $elements.first().fadeOut(duration, function() {
             fadeInOutList($elements.slice(1), duration, delay)
          })
       }, delay)
     })
}


fadeInOutList($('img'), 500, 1000)
```

```css
img {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://vk.com/images/gifts/256/71.jpg" />
<img src="http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png" />
<img src="http://vk.com/images/gifts/256/44.jpg" />
<img src="http://breckon.eu/toby/fundipbook/materials/gallery/cameraman.jpg" />
```

Comment: There's nothing in your example - doesn't look like it works.